# Magento 2 braintree payment options invisible on shopping cart

Tags: magento2, braintree

Braintree payment options[paypal and apple pay] doesn't show in minicart. My site is upgraded from Magento 2.1.7 to 2.2.4. The problem is in the database. But cant identifies the fix. Can anyone give a solution?